# Show: $\text{im } f \cap \text{ker } f = \{0\} \iff \text{ker } f \circ f = \text{ker } f$ for vectorspace $V$ with linear function $f:V\rightarrow V$

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vectorspace with linear function $f:V\rightarrow V$
Show that:

$\text{im } f \cap \text{ker } f = \{0\} \iff \text{ker } f \circ f= \text{ker } f$

---

This is my current proof; I'm certain the idea is correct, however it feels a bit slopy, so I would appreciate suggestions for improvements:

Let $x\in V \implies f(x) \in \text{im } f$

\begin{align}
&\text{im } f \cap \text{ker }  f = \{0\}\\
\iff & \forall f(x)\in \text{ker } f : f(x)=0\\
\iff & \forall f(x)\in \text{ker } f : f(x)=0 : x \in \text{ker } f \\
\iff & \forall f(x)\in \text{ker } f : x \in \text{ker } f \\
\iff & \forall x\in \text{ker } f \circ f : x \in \text{ker } f\\
\iff & \text{ker } f \circ f = \text{ker } f
\end{align}

Comment: What is $\ker f \circ f$?

Comment: To cure this sloppiness, rewrite your proof with no $\forall f(x)$. Only one letter after $\forall$. And replace "Let $x\in V \implies f(x) \in \text{im } f$" by something more useful (or simply remove it).

Comment: [Your first version](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/4874177/1) was much better than this second one. It only needed a $\forall x\in V$ just after every opening parenthesis, and the suppression of the line containing two $\iff$.

Comment: More generally, you can prove similarly that for every maps $f:X\to Y,g:Y\to Z$ and every subsets $C\subseteq Z, B\subseteq Y$,
$$\operatorname{im}(f)\cap g^{-1}(C)\subseteq B\iff(g\circ f)^{-1}(C)\subseteq f^{-1}(B).$$

Comment: @YathirajSharma $\ker f\circ f$ is $\ker (f\circ f)$; $u\circ v$ is standard notation for composition of functions.

Comment: OMG! Okay it is $\ker(f\circ f)$. Why didn't I read it that way I am wondering! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it will be clearer to write separately.

$\Rightarrow$ Obviously,we have $\ker f\subseteq \ker f\circ f$.So we just need to prove $\ker f\supseteq \ker f\circ f$.For every $x\in \ker f\circ f$,there is $f(f(x))=0$.Hence,$f(x)\in\ker f$.For $f(x)\in \mathrm{im}f$,we have $f(x)\in \mathrm{im}f\cap\ker f$.Thus, $f(x)=0$,$x\in \ker f$,then $\ker f\circ f\subseteq \ker f$,$\ker f\circ f= \ker f$.

$\Leftarrow$  For every $x\in\ker f\cap \mathrm{im}f$,$x\in\ker f$ thus $f(x)=0$.At the same time, $x\in\mathrm{im}f$.So there exists $x'\in  V$,such that $ x=f(x')$.Therefore, $f(x)=f(f(x'))=0.$Hence,$x'\in\ker f\circ f$.Because $\ker f=\ker f\circ f$,we have $x'\in\ker f$,which means $x=0$.As the result, $\ker f\cap \mathrm{im}f=0$